# Change value of "budget" to categories levels in R

Tags: r

I have (for now) one question and I can't find a solution.

Background: Termpaper, topic: Using a dataset from Kaggle that scraped imdb for movie data. analysis of correlation budget -> imdb rating and revenue -> imdb rating.

I have the variable budget (min = 11.000, max 300.000.000) and would like to categorize this into levels (low-budget/<2,5mil, medium-low, medium, high, extremely high).

I want to get a boxplot from this data afterwards. Any hints?

Comment: `cut()` may do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
codage <-function(name,ncateg){
    bornes <-quantile(name, probs = seq(0,1,by=1/ncateg), na.rm =TRUE ,names     = TRUE)
    Amax <-aggregate(name,list(Nom=cut(name,bornes ,include.lowest=T,label=F)),max)
    Amin <-aggregate(name,list(Nom=cut(name,bornes ,include.lowest=T,label=F)),min)
    Afreq<-as.matrix(summary(as.factor(cut(na.omit(name),bornes,include.lowest=T,label=F))))
    limites <-as.data.frame(cbind(Amin[,1],Amin[,2],Amax[,2],Afreq))
    names(limites)<-c("Classe","Mini","Maxi","Effectif")

    manques <-length(name)-length(na.omit(name))


    varfac <-cut(name,bornes ,include.lowest=T,label=F)

    as.factor(varfac)
}
```

just type codage(variable you want to categorize,number of categories)

Comment: Error in typeof(x) : object 'nom' not found

dont know if I made a mistake there?

Comment: Can you try again now please ?

Comment: I got a solution to split the budget in non-equal levels:

Answer (score 0):

```
    data_op %>% 
  mutate(level = car::recode(data_op$level, 
                             "1:2500000 = 'Low Budget'; 
                             2500001:30000000 = 'Medium Budget';
                             30000001:199999999 = 'High Budget';
                             200000000:300000000 = 'Most Expensive Film Budget'",
                             as.factor.result = TRUE)) -> data_op
```